# Possible isomorphisms between D2 and subgroups of S4

Tags: group-theory, permutations

One common way to find such a isomorphism would be to use the Cayley Theorem.

My prof. also mentioned that there are many other isomorphism, such as mapping the generators for D2 to (1,2) and (3,4) respectively or mapping the generators for D2 to (1,3) and (2,4) respectively, where the mappings are defined as f(ab) = f(a)f(b).

How did he derive such isomorphisms?

Edit: D2 refers to the dihedral group of order 4. S4 refers to the permutation group on a set of 4 objects.

Comment: What is $D2$? $S4$ is, I guess, the symmetrc group of degree $4$?

Comment: Please add that information to the question itself.

Comment: Now, since the two groups have different numbers of elements, there is no isomorphism between them!

Comment: sorry i forgotten to mention i meant subgroups of S4

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez i meant subgroups of S4, can u help me?

Comment: @yh05 Hi, just to clarify. Are you asking how to show that $D2$ and $\{(),(1,2),(3,4),(1,2)(3,4)\}$ are isomorphic? Or how your prof made the connection between the two? If it is the latter, Cayley's theorem admits the existence of such an isomorphism, and if one considers the orders of the elements in $D2$, it is not difficult to guess the subgroup in $S4$ and proving the isomorphism after.

Comment: @Troy im curious how did he form the many examples for isomorphisms. i want to know the thought process.

Comment: @yh05 I'm not particularly sure if there is a sure-fire way of doing it, but it's helpful to note that in the group $D_2 = \{1,r,m,rm\}$, all non-identity elements have order 2, and so, we expect the permutations chosen from $S_4$ to also have order 2. Any permutations with cycle type 2 or 2,2 will work in this case. Of course, for the resulting set to be a group and an isomorphism, we have to choose them wisely, but that's a good first step I think.

Comment: @Troy How can we choose them correctly? besides choosing 2 permutations, $a$ and $b$ of order 2 to be the images of generators of $D2$, i also have to ensure that they have similar structure by making sure $ab = ba$, $a*a = 1$ and $b*b = 1$.

There's no quick way besides trying out the different possibilities?

Comment: @yh05 If we are talking about proving a group to be isomorphic to another, proving homomorphism and the bijective nature of the mapping is sufficient to ensure isomorphism. That, I believe is a straightforward exercise. As for coming up with an isomorphism, you don't have to try all the possibilities. But like I said, choose wisely, by considering the generators of each group and their respective orders. As far as I'm aware, I don't think that there is a 'theorem' for a quick way to identify isomorphisms, save for Cayley's theorem.